# An expression of [noun] is [noun] -is it without/with article?

Tags: articles

In day-to-day conversation, we often use the phrases this way...

> Whatever it is, game is game 
>   Whether you like it or not, gift is gift 
>  Believe it or not, record is record

In all these expressions, do we use ***an indefinite*** article? Or, it's okay without it? In either case, how? Why?

> Whatever it is, ***a*** game is ***a*** game 
>   Whether you like it or not, ***a*** gift is ***a*** gift 
>  Believe it or not, ***a*** record is ***a*** record.

Or, is this acceptable?

> Whatever it is, ***a*** game is game *(no article second time?)*

Comment: Use the same thing both times: definite, indefinite, or no article as appropriate.

Comment: I see. Thanks @snailplane I had a doubt about it as I have read all the styles. But again, as a native, which style do you prefer? Also, how is it correct to have *no* article?

Answer (score 3):

As snailplane [comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33084/an-expression-of-noun-is-noun-is-it-without-with-article#comment62016_33084) on the question,

> Use the same thing both times: definite, indefinite, or no article as appropriate.

To determine what is appropriate, there are some general rules and there's almost certainly at least one relevant question on ELL.

1. A mass noun or a plural takes no article

   > Whatever else it is, water is water
   >   Whatever else they are, lions are lions
2. A generic reference to a singular thing uses  the indefinite article

   > Whether you like it or not, a gift is a gift
3. A reference to a specific thing which is in context uses the definite article

   > Believe it or not, the record **is** the record.

Because you are emphasising that A is B, whatever else might pertain, it's necessary to keep both halves of the phrase the same with the same article (or none) either side of the copula *be*. Changing the article radically changes the expression from "That's just the way it is" to something specific:

4. > Whether you like it or not, the gift is a gift

   That is, **that** gift which we're talking about really is a gift and you don't need to pay for it.